# select filter returning undefined jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a option selected based on the text or value of a element in a div tag. For example, the div element holds 'Reports: Report Name'. I trimmed the whitespace and removed 'Reports:' so just the report name would be returned, but it is saying it is undefined. What's confusing is that I did it in a table and it returned fine. Here is my code:

```
var reports = $.trim($('#reports_' + id).html());
var report_selected = reports.replace('Reports:', '');

var highlight_report = $('#edit_reports option').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text() === report_selected || $(this).val === report_selected);
});

$('#edit_reports').val(highlight_report.val());
```

and the html select menu:

```
<select id="edit_reports" name="edit_reports[]" multiple
            style='height: 200px; width: 240px; padding-left: 2px;'>
        <?php
             $q = pg_query("SELECT * FROM tblmenuitems ORDER BY name");
             while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['menuitemid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
        <?php   
            }                
        ?>
</select>
```

Like I said, it worked fine for the other part of my code but for this it isn't, it is just returning undefined. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't find reports_+id.
Check again.
Because Your code is not sure.

Comment: this is the field: <div style="border-top: thin solid #036;" id="reports_272">Reports: Ad Hoc Universe</div>

Comment: and this code (alert(report_selected); return false;) returns 'Ad Hoc Universe'

Comment: Oh.i don't seem it.